# Image blur on loading the image to imageview

Tags: android

While I load an image from SD to imageview,  the image is  blur.

To improve image quality... any solution..?

Here is the code...

```
Bitmap image = null;
                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null,
                                    null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    image = decodeFile(file);

                } catch (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Image size is too large !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Try with different image !",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_mainImg);
                mainImage.setImageBitmap(image);
```

Comment: <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/img_mainImg"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image from data return low quality image. Try using a file path and get the image from file path.

here i show to get last image path

```
private String getLastImagePath() {
        final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " DESC";
        Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns,
                null, null, imageOrderBy);
        if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
            String fullPath = imageCursor.getString(imageCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
            return fullPath;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

So, Same way get full image path to convert bitmap and show it imageview.